# Centerize materializecss icon

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

I have  a bin icon which I want to make it appear in the center of a container.I have tried text-align center and vertical-align:middle.
However no matter what I do the icon seems to be a litte bit to the right side.

Here is a snippet

```css
.container{
  border:4px solid blue;
}
i{
  margin-left:50%;
  margin-right:50%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <i class='material-icons large'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Any Ideas how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `margin-left:50%;` you aren't taking the width of the icon into account.  So the icon display starts in the middle and then 'adds' its width from there.

```css
.container{
  border:4px solid blue;
}
i{
  margin-left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <i class='material-icons large'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Another solution is to `text-align:center;` the `.container` css surrounding the `<i class="material-icons large">` and remove the `margin` and `text-align` from the `i` css.

```css
.container{
  border:4px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}
i{

}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='container'>
  <i class='material-icons large'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're setting `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `50%`, while not accounting for the width of the icon itself. As the icon is `84px` wide, you can centralise it by dividing `84px` by 2, and then subtracting this value (`42px`) from each of your margins.

You can do this dynamically by making use of CSS' **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** method, as can be seen in the following:

```css
.container {
  border: 4px solid blue;
}

i {
  margin-left: calc(50% - (84px / 2));
  margin-right: calc(50% - (84px / 2));
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='container'>
  <i class='material-icons large'>delete</i>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)